# What is the most complete collection of CR versions?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

To my knowledge, [this](https://yawgatog.com/resources/rules-changes/) is the most complete collection of versions of the Comprehensive Rules, including a diff between successive updates. However, it has been discontinued after the Ixalan update.

Is there a more comprehensive resource for this kind of information, i.e. one that covers a wider date range, especially one that is up-to-date? The raw data would be sufficient for an answer, a changelog or other features would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Using the WaybackMachine from https://archive.org/ to search Wizards website, the earliest listing of a 'Comprehensive Rules' pdf is for rules effective as of [September 25, 2014](https://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/MagicCompRules_20140926.pdf) (the day before Khans of Tarkir released).

https://web.archive.org/web/20141101000000*/https://magic.wizards.com/en/rules

Additional searches on Archive.org I found some Pocket Players' Guide books, and set-specific rulebooks: [https://archive.org/search.php?query=subject%3A%22magic%3A+the+gathering%22&and[]=creator%3A%22wizards+of+the+coast%22](https://archive.org/search.php?query=subject%3A%22magic%3A+the+gathering%22&and%5B%5D=creator%3A%22wizards+of+the+coast%22)

Comment: The rules records go back earlier than that specific address, that's just when the site got redesigned. They were up [from 1999 onwards](https://web.archive.org/web/19991002044300/http://www.wizards.com/Magic/MTG_Rules.asp) when the comp rules first existed, and then [moved in 2002](https://web.archive.org/web/20020210205505/http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=magic/rules/tourneyplayer) and [again in 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20080831121202/http://www.wizards.com/magic/TCG/Resources.aspx?x=magic/rules).